# how can i check that a frame is open or not in java?

Tags: java, forms, swing, netbeans, panel

i can open a form or another forms when button is clicked in netbeans.
such as the following code

```
private void button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    frame1 fr = new frame1();
    desktop.add(fr);
    fr.setVisible(true);}
```

but i want to control that is current form is open or close? if current form is open then when i click same button not open current form again until its closed the same form. how can i make it? there is some methods like isclosed(), isDisplayable(), but i dont khow how can i use these? please give me advice.

Comment: This problem would likely vanish if you use one `JFrame` and modal `JDialog` instances for the rest of the free floating GUI elements.

Comment: I suggest that you begin following classname casing conventions. Classnames are to be in CamelCase, as in `Frame1`, rather than `frame1`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: **Modal** dialogs may or may not be appropriate here. What if the user should be able to interact with the main `JFrame` and one or more other modal `JDialog`s at once?

Comment: @Zéychin  What if, maybe, perhaps..  the OP can clarify their requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Boolean variables to determine whether or not the allowance of opening a frame.

example:

```
//declaring the boolean in a class in which both frames can access
public final class Allow {
    private Allow(){}
    public static Boolean allow_ = true;
}
```

In your main frame code where you open the secondary frame you can do this

```
if(Allow.allow_ == true) {
    Allow.allow_ = false;
    secondFrame sFrame_ = new secondFrame();
    sFrame_.setVisible(true);
} else {
    //alert the user that the frame is already open
    //I recommend a JOptionPane such as this
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This window is already open");
}
```

So now the second frame is open, and now it will only let you open it if allow_ is true.

Now when you close the second frame you do this:

```
Allow.allow_ = true;
secondFrame.this.setVisible(false);
secondFrame.this.dispose();
```

Now the second frame is closed, and will now be allowed to be opened once again.

Comment: thank you sou much. i also thought that such yours idea. but i didn't know how to implement that. trick is that, i add last code group to method which is frameclosed event. thanks again :)

Comment: It really helped me implementing the issue in my application. +1